# Open Sans and sans-serif not displaying correctly in every webbrowser

Tags: html, google-chrome, fonts, microsoft-edge

Websites that use Open Sans font are displayed with a strange type of handwriting font. I cannot figure out where this obvious error comes from.

I have tried:

- In-Private
- Disabled all extentions
- Chrome
- Edge

I have verified that the font should be Open Sans and what it looks like on another machine. I hope someone can point me to the solution to my issue.

[image: Correctly displayed]

[image: Wrongly displayed]

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Please delete this.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/sp3du8/strange_font_rendering_in_chrome_and_edge_open/); it seems that it's some sort of bug which makes Chrome think it can substitute Open Sans with a different type. In my case it was a font named "Andalusea" which I at one point installed.

After removing the font, the issue is resolved.

To find out which font your system is replacing Open Sans with, please do the following (in Chrome):

1. Open the website that is showing the weird font
2. Open developer tools (Press F12 in windows, or right-click the page and select Inspect)
3. Go to the Computed section on the right hand side of the tools and scroll all the way to the bottom to "Rendered fonts".

There it will show you the culprit.